# ¿Cómo combinar operadores en Sequelize?

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js

Tengo esta variable:

```
var options = {
    where: [
        {mes: mes, any: any},
        {mes: mes + 1, any: any, dia: 1}
    ],

};
```

Aquí se fijan las condiciones de la consulta, combinado `AND` y `OR`. Lo que se intenta es seleccionar los registros de un mes y año, y también el primer día del mismo año, pero mes siguiente. 
Funciona para la primera condición de mes y año, pero cuando añado la segunda con el primer día del mes siguiente no devuelve nada.

Si alguien tiene alguna solución se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo de esta manera

```
where: { 
    $or: [
        {
            $and: {
                mes: mes,
                anio: anio
            }
        },
        {
            $and: {
                mes: mes + 1,
                dia: 1,
                anio: anio
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Equivale en SQL a

```
where (anio = :anio and mes = :mes ) or (anio = :anio and mes = :mes + 1 and dia = 1)
```

Puedes revisar como usar los operadores en la [domumentación](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/)

Comment: Debe haber algún error de sintaxis por "unexpected token {" en la primera variable mes.

Comment: Si, puse parentesis demás en la definición de cada clave : valor, modifique la respuesta

Comment: Todavía no lo he probado bien, pero sintácticamente no presenta error.

Comment: Carlos, como decía sintaxis bien, pero en ejecución sí da un error de sintaxis --> syntax error at or near ",".

Comment: @Jota edite la respuesta, me avisas si funciona para eliminar mi respuesta que puse en la nueva pregunta que formulaste sobre este mismo tema

Comment: ya estoy en ello...

Answer (score 0):

Por que no pruebas usando el **where** de la siguiente manera:

```
where: ["(mes = ?) OR (mes = ? and day=?) ", {mes, mes+1, 1}]
```

Exitos!

Comment: No funciona, dice que mes es ambiguo. Y tampoco estás seleccionado la variable any. Gracias igual.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer usando querys directamente en sequelize de la siguiente manera:

```
     YourSequelizeModel.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE "COLUMN" = ? AND 
     "PARAM"= ? ',{ replacements: [param1,param2], type: 
     Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT } )
```

Donde cada parámetro se va remplazando en los *replacements* en la medida que se van declarando en el query.